# does "a light was struck" mean "To create a flame (using a match, flint, etc.)"?

Tags: meaning

does "a light was struck" mean "To create a flame (using a match, flint, etc.)"?

"something ignited preceding the..."?

Mr. Fay then asked that his coat
should be removed. We heard instantly a violent twitch, and here
occurred the most remarkable fact. **A light was struck** before the coat had
quite, left Mr. Fay's person, and it was seen quitting him, plucked off him
upwards. It flew up to the chandelier, where it hung for a moment and
then fell to the ground.

Comment: _A light was struck_ means _someone created a flame_. In this case, assuming we're still with the spiritualists, it presumably means that a light appeared _as though_ someone had struck a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google shows that quote is from, "A Biography of the Brothers Davenport", T.L. Nichols, 1864. From the year, we can infer that there weren't electric lights to be switched on, so you are correct, it means "to create a flame (using a match, flint, etc.)

This link searches that book for instances of "struck", and several of them refer to lights being struck. It's so common that it must refer to the use of a match, not a flint.

[Google Books](https://tinyurl.com/y9fgdckb)